# Array value isn't removed when deleting HTML table row

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML template that lets the user add rows to a table. But when I delete a specific row from the table, and I click on the `welcome to our website` button, it still shows the deleted records in the array variable. How can I make it to also delete the array entry that corresponds to the delete-action, so the array corresponds to what is being shown in the table?

As you can see in this image, I added two records which are "Subject,Contain,1" and "Subject,Contain,2":

[image]

But whenever I delete the first record, which is "Subject,Contain,1", the array is still showing that record:

[image]

```js
//add tablebox
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").on("click", function() {
    para = document.getElementById("Parameter").value;
    condi = document.getElementById("Condition").value;
    value2match = document.getElementById("valuetomatch").value;

    if (para && condi && value2match !== null) {
      var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      var row = table.insertRow(-1);
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
      var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

      cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("Parameter").value;
      cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("Condition").value;
      cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("valuetomatch").value;
      cell4.innerHTML =
        '<button  class = "del_img "onClick="delSpec(this)"><img src="deleteimg.png" width="30" height="30"></button> </div>';

      var myTab = document.getElementById("myTable");
      var tableData = [];

      // LOOP THROUGH EACH ROW OF THE TABLE AFTER HEADER.
      for (i = 1; i < myTab.rows.length; i++) {
        // GET THE CELLS COLLECTION OF THE CURRENT ROW.
        var objCells = myTab.rows.item(i).cells;

        // LOOP THROUGH EACH CELL OF THE CURENT ROW TO READ CELL VALUES.
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          tableData.push(objCells.item(j).innerHTML);
        }
      }

      document.getElementById("buttonSubmit").onclick = function() {
        alert(tableData);
      };
      //close the modal
      modal.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      alert("All the input box cannot be empty!");
    }
  });
});

function delSpec(node) {
  r = node.parentNode.parentNode;
  r.parentNode.removeChild(r);
}

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
};

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
};

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

```css
.buttonSubmit {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.del_img {
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

body {
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
}

.button {
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #ff9633;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-left: 500px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: "\00bb";
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 45%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #ff9633;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #ff9633;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ff9633;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #fa7d34;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,500" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</style>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div id="myBtn1"><a href="#AddCon">Alert Policies</a></div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Test3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">Test4</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Alert Policies</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p style="font-size: 14px">
        Please select an event parameter as well as the condition type and value that apply.
      </p>

      <!-- parameter drop down -->
      <form method="post">
        <label for="Parameter">
          <b style="font-size: 13px">
            Event parameter to evaluate
          </b></label
        >
        <select
          name="Parameter"
          id="Parameter"
          style="width: 340px; font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif"
        >
          <option disabled selected value>select a parameter</option>
          <option value="Subject">Subject</option>
          <option value="Text">Text</option>
        </select>
        <br /><br />

        <label for="Condition">
          <b style="font-size: 13px"> Type of condition </b></label
        >
        <select
          name="Condition"
          id="Condition"
          style="
            width: 340px;
            margin-left: 69px;
            font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
          "
        >
          <option disabled selected value>select a condition</option>
          <option value="Equals">Equals</option>
          <option value="Contain">Contain</option>
          <option value="NotContain">Does not contain</option>
        </select>
        <br /><br />

        <label for="valuetomatch">
          <b style="font-size: 13px"> Value to match</b></label
        >
        <input
          type="text"
          id="valuetomatch"
          name="valuetomatch"
          style="
            width: 333px;
            margin-left: 80px;
            font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
          "
        />
        <br />
        <br />
      </form>
      <button class="button"><span>OK</span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Event Parameter</th>
    <th>Condition</th>
    <th>Value to match</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />

<button id="buttonSubmit">Welcome to our website</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is no surprise that `tableData` also contains the deleted items, as you never delete anything from `tableData`. The only thing your code does with `tableData` is calling `.push`.

You will need to delete the item from `tableData` at the moment the user performs the delete action. So extend your `delSpec` function as follows:

```
function delSpec(node) {
  // Always declare your variables! Use `let` or `const` or `var`:
  let r = node.parentNode.parentNode;
  // Remove the row from the array:
  tableData.splice(r.rowIndex - 1, 1);
  // Remove the row from the HTML table:
  r.parentNode.removeChild(r);
}
```

As the `rowIndex` also takes the header row into account (which is not represented in `tableData`), the above code needs to subtract 1 from `rowIndex`.

You have some other errors that need to be corrected for the above to work:

- `tableData` should be a global variable so it is accessible in the different handlers
- `tableData` should then only get the new row added to it.
- The submit click handler should not be defined in the other handler, but outside of it.

Here is the corrected code:

```
//declare the array as a global
var tableData = [];
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".button").on("click", function () {
    para = document.getElementById("Parameter").value;
    condi = document.getElementById("Condition").value;
    value2match = document.getElementById("valuetomatch").value;

    if (para && condi && value2match !== null) {
      var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      var row = table.insertRow(-1);
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
      var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

      cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("Parameter").value;
      cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("Condition").value;
      cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("valuetomatch").value;
      cell4.innerHTML =
        '<button  class = "del_img "onClick="delSpec(this)"><img src="deleteimg.png" width="30" height="30"></button> </div>';

      var myTab = document.getElementById("myTable");

      // Only add the new row:
      tableData.push([
        document.getElementById("Parameter").value,
        document.getElementById("Condition").value,
        document.getElementById("valuetomatch").value
      ]);

      modal.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      alert("All the input box cannot be empty!");
    }
  });
  // Move click handler outside of the other handler
  $("#buttonSubmit").onclick = function () {
    alert(tableData);
  };
});

function delSpec(node) {
  let r = node.parentNode.parentNode;
  tableData.splice(r.rowIndex - 1, 1);
  r.parentNode.removeChild(r);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the respond. But after writing `  tableData.splice(r.rowIndex - 1, 1);` to my `delSpec` function, I cant even press the delete button.

Comment: What do you have in the console? There should be a message. (I would have tested the code, but your code snippet in the question is not working at all. If you can include code in your question that *reproduces* the original issue, then I promise I can give you a working answer).

Comment: @trincot, the code snippet is working. What do you mean doesn’t work?

Comment: I cannot get rows in that table. Did you check the console?

Comment: I can create a row in the table by clicking the alert policies on the left top menu. It will pop up a modal and you can insert data in the table.  Is that what you want to try or I miss something?

Comment: I entered data in the popup, but then nothing happens. There is no Add button or something like that. And if I press enter, the form submits, and the snippet goes blank. I have not found a way to enter a row in the table.

Comment: There is an OK button, you can expand the page on full screen. You will see it.

Comment: Ah, it appears outside of the popup area. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @trincot It work great on my side. You explain it very well thank you for the solution and explanation !